# ansible to read openssl public key (.pem) content from user input and create a file on server

Tags: shell, ssl, scripting, ansible, public-key

I m basically creating a playbook for creating pkcs12 file where in it asks for public key(.pem) and private key. my private key is on server so i can pass location of file. but my public key(.pem) is not residing on server nor i can copy paste from local.
so i want to create an ansible-playbook which can read public key content from user as a variable and create a file on the remote server to use in pkcs12 file creation.

my publickey content is spreaded across multiple lines like below.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(64-character alphanumeric content)
.
.
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

can you suggest simple way to achieve this.
i am using copy module 'content' option, but unable to achieve this.

```
  tasks:
  - name: copy content
    copy:
     content: "{{ my_pub_key }}"
     dest: /tmp/{{file}}.pem

ansible-playbook abc.yaml -e "my_pub_key=
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.
.
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

"~
please suggest if there is any another way to achieve this ?

Comment: For whatever it's worth, one can always derive the public key given a private key: `openssl rsa -pubout -in /my/secret/key.pem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure, what do you mean by below statement. From the question, guessing nothing was written to the destination file.

> ...but unable to achieve this...

Your task looks fine. However, to pass multiline string as a parameter, add quote (`'`) to define variable value like this.

```
$ ansible-playbook abc.yaml -e "my_pub_key='
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.
.
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----'"
```

Comment: Please fix your answer to not use unicode quote characters (both the single and the doublequote) since they will not be correctly interpreted by any shell that I'm aware of

Comment: It was a copy/paste of the working command. Not sure if anything changed during pasting or formatting. Thanks for the feedback.